# Does Time Machine improve startup time?

Tags: macos, time-machine, startup

This may initially sound like a question, and I'm by no means a amateur user of the OSX Operating system(s).

However, upon recently upgrading to Yosemite, my system has become SUPER slow to boot, and I'm wondering if Time Machine will at all aid the start up time by distributing the burden to two disks?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Per request...

```
EtreCheck version: 2.1.8 (121)
Report generated March 5, 2015 at 10:04:05 PM PST
Download EtreCheck from http://etresoft.com/etrecheck

Click the [Click for support] links for help with non-Apple products.
Click the [Click for details] links for more information about that line.

Hardware Information: ℹ️
    iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012) (Technical Specifications)
    iMac - model: iMac13,1
    1 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU: 4-core
    8 GB RAM Upgradeable
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
    Bluetooth: Good - Handoff/Airdrop2 supported
    Wireless:  en1: 802.11 a/b/g/n

Video Information: ℹ️
    NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M - VRAM: 512 MB
        iMac 1920 x 1080

System Software: ℹ️
    OS X 10.10.2 (14C109) - Time since boot: 2:34:0

Disk Information: ℹ️
    APPLE HDD ST1000LM024 disk0 : (1 TB)
        EFI (disk0s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
        Macintosh HD (disk0s2) / : 999.35 GB (469.15 GB free)
        Recovery HD (disk0s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB 

USB Information: ℹ️
    Seagate BUP Slim Mac SL 1 TB
        EFI (disk1s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
        Time Machine (disk1s2) /Volumes/Time Machine : 999.86 GB (846.04 GB free)
    Apple Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) 
    Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 
        Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 

Thunderbolt Information: ℹ️
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Gatekeeper: ℹ️
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Kernel Extensions: ℹ️
        /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (4.3.18) [Click for support]
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (4.3.18) [Click for support]
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (4.3.18) [Click for support]
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (4.3.18) [Click for support]

        /System/Library/Extensions
    [loaded]    com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower (1.6.6 - SDK 10.6) [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.aliph.driver.jstub (1.1.2 - SDK 10.7) [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.philips.iokit.DLconnect (85) [Click for support]

Startup Items: ℹ️
    Freecorder: Path: /Library/StartupItems/Freecorder
    Startup items are obsolete in OS X Yosemite

Launch Agents: ℹ️
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.newwellnesssolutions.DLconnectMonitor.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist [Click for support]
    [failed]    com.promethean.activmgr.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist [Click for support]

Launch Daemons: ℹ️
    [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.autodesk.adlm.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.backburner_manager.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.backburner_server.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.autodesk.backburner_start.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.dl_mpd.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.sw_bwmgr.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.sw_dbd.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.sw_ifffs.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.sw_probed.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.sw_server.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.autodesk.sw_start.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.autodesk.wiretapgateway.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.autodesk.wiretapgateway_start.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.daemon.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.ManyCamLLC.videodevice.daemon.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.JavaUpdateHelper.plist [Click for support]
    [failed]    com.promethean.activhardwareservice.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.rogueamoeba.instanton-agent.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.ubuntu.one.fsevents.plist [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    org.freedesktop.dbus-system.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.startup.plist [Click for support]

User Launch Agents: ℹ️
    [failed]    com.google.Chrome.framework.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.nchsoftware.debut.schedule.LikeSurvey.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.spotify.webhelper.plist [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist [Click for support]

User Login Items: ℹ️
    Dropbox    Application Hidden (/Applications/Dropbox.app)
    Jawbone Updater    UNKNOWN  (missing value)
    Music Manager    Application Hidden (/Users/[redacted]/Library/PreferencePanes/MusicManager.prefPane/Contents/Helpers/MusicManagerHelper.app)
    BitTorrent Sync    UNKNOWN  (missing value)

Internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
    Unity Web Player: Version: UnityPlayer version 4.3.5f1 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    FlashPlayer-10.6: Version: 16.0.0.305 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    Default Browser: Version: 600 - SDK 10.10
    Flash Player: Version: 16.0.0.305 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
    o1dbrowserplugin: Version: 5.40.2.0 - SDK 10.8 [Click for support]
    SharePointBrowserPlugin: Version: 14.3.9 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    googletalkbrowserplugin: Version: 5.40.2.0 - SDK 10.8 [Click for support]
    Silverlight: Version: 5.1.30514.0 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    DirectorShockwave: Version: 12.1.2r152 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    JavaAppletPlugin: Version: Java 8 Update 31 Check version

User internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
    BlueStacks Install Detector: Version: Unknown
    NPRoblox: Version: 1, 2, 8, 25 - SDK 10.10 [Click for support]
    Google Earth Web Plug-in: Version: 7.1 [Click for support]

Audio Plug-ins: ℹ️
    Hear: Version: 1.1.6 - SDK 10.8 [Click for support]

3rd Party Preference Panes: ℹ️
    remoting_host_prefpane  [Click for support]
    Flash Player  [Click for support]
    Java  [Click for support]
    MusicManager  [Click for support]

Time Machine: ℹ️
    Mobile backups: OFF
    Auto backup: YES
    Volumes being backed up:
        Macintosh HD: Disk size: 999.35 GB Disk used: 530.20 GB
    Destinations:
        Time Machine [Local] 
        Total size: 0 B 
        Total number of backups: 0 
        Oldest backup: - 
        Last backup: - 
        Size of backup disk: Too small
            Backup size 0 B < (Disk used 530.20 GB X 3)

Top Processes by CPU: ℹ️
         3%    WindowServer
         3%    backupd
         2%    mds
         1%    mds_stores
         0%    fontd

Top Processes by Memory: ℹ️
    790 MB    com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond
    283 MB    mds_stores
    180 MB    Finder
    120 MB    mds
    112 MB    ocspd

Virtual Memory Information: ℹ️
    859 MB    Free RAM
    3.62 GB    Active RAM
    2.86 GB    Inactive RAM
    1.09 GB    Wired RAM
    131.61 GB    Page-ins
    32 MB    Page-outs

Diagnostics Information: ℹ️
    Mar 5, 2015, 07:29:33 PM    Self test - passed

    Standard users cannot read /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.
    Run as an administrator account to see more information.
```

Comment: If anything, Time Machine would contribute to slow start up. Not Time Machine itself, but the external disk (which is mounted during the boot process). This is highly unlikely culprit however. Slow startups can be caused by many things - from 3rd party kernel extensions to a failing internal drive. Download and run http://etresoft.com/etrecheck and update your post with a copy of the report.

Comment: @njboot I updated it :)

Answer (score 1):

[njboot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/62132/njboot) is not completely wrong..If there is a chance to do what you are suggesting, it would make the booting process slower. The presence of a timecapsule is found by osx, only after the bonjour service detects the Timecapsule. Bonjour service kicks in only after a user logs in.

The slowness may be caused by the sheer amount of data that needs to be transfered to memory (Which more or less increases with every update). I suggest you to add a SSD and install the os in that. You can still use your existing 1TB ADD as a secondary storage to keep your files.